# codeigniter sessions stopped working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have a old website which uses codeigniter 3.0  it was working fine for 2 years  until today

I couldn't login so i did bit of investigation and found that session didn't work ... basically it would change to null after each redirect

So i wrote a little code to see whats going on

```
 class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function a(){

        $this->session->set_userdata(array('test'=>123 ));
        echo 'stored@';

            $md_id =  $this->session->userdata();  
            var_dump($md_id);



    }

    function b(){
            $md_id =  $this->session->userdata();  
            var_dump($md_id);

    }
```

and here is the result for /a

```
stored@array(2) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1516110913) ["test"]=> int(123) }
```

and result for /b

```
array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1516110943) }
```

here is my config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'rozsess';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 86400;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

i've looked in my database the sessions are there but when i looked in my cookies the hash code for `test` session wasn't there only hash code for a regenerate session

i've tried to set domain name in config and play with exp date with no result

i've no idea what has happen it seems like CI keeps deleting my old cookies or something anyone has any idea what is going on ?

------------------------- UPDATE ------------------------------------

so i've emptied my session table and tried to log in ... so it logged in and automatically logged out and redirected to login page ... thats 3 request

1 - logged in 
2 - redirected to dashboard (here it gets logged out) 
3 - redirected to login page

here is what my db shows

[image]

as you can see the first row with has `md_id` in it and its the one with session data ... but right after that there are 2 other rows

and my cookie manager points to the last row  hash code

[image]

so basically the problem is CI regenerates a cookie for each request ! thats why it cant find my session .... it deletes my session cookie and replaced it with another one right in the next request ... and its for all the request if i refresh any page 10 times i get 10 rows in db

Comment: Looks like a cookie name collision to me.

Comment: @Narf  any guess what might cuz  that ?

Comment: The same cookie name being sent with different parameters; or if it lacks a domain flag - it being sent from both `domain.tld` and `sub.domain.tld`.

Comment: @Narf well we did just add a subdomain to the server but there is a wordpress website on that ,  dont know how it might be sending a cookie name with the codeigniter session cookie name `rozsess`

Comment: Go check and see ... I mean, it's clear that you're lost on this, but ultimately only you can debug it - your apps, your cookies. Inspect the request, response headers and see if/where they get lost.

Comment: @Narf i think i found the problem ... please check the update in the bottom of my question ... any idea what might be cuzing CI to act like this ?

Comment: Curious, does it do this in other browsers?